# Pixmaps, ByteBuffers, and Textures....Oh my

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, libgdx

My ultimate goal is to take a specific region of the screen, and redraw it somewhere else. For example, take a square from the upper left hand corner of the screen and redraw it on the lower right hand corner, so that it is basically a copy of that screen section; kind of like a minimap, but at the same scale as the original. I have looked in to pixmaps and bytebuffers. Also maybe copying that region from the backbuffer somehow. Wondering the best way to go about this. Any help is appreciated. I am using opengl es and libgdx for what it's worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a frame buffer object (FBO) -- basically think of it as "render to texture". You render your scene to the buffer rather than the screen. Then, after the scene is done you render simpler things like quads to the "real" screen, using the FBO as a texture sampler in your shaders. This means you could render multiple quads each using some subset of the image or write more involved shader that knows how to pull data out of the texture the way you want.

I'm not very familiar with libgdx but you'd be using this thing I believe: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html

Comment: This is what I basically ended up doing. I rendered to the frame buffer then rendered that to the screen. I could then pick the area from the created frame buffer and redisplay that again elsewhere on the screen. Seems to be working, thanks.